# Localizing DateSpinner month names - Flex Mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I want to translate Flex Mobile DateSpinner month names into Turkish ones but I couldn't cause of lacking locale support for turkish language, and even when I created a new locale using copylocale command (http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.com/2011/04/flex-41-creating-new-locale-for-i18n.html) Eclipse shows me an error below:

```
unable to open '/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.7.0.349722/dcradSwcs/4.5/locale/tr_TR'
```

Is there any workaround? maybe by extending component but I don't have much experience with flex - actionscript.. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: adding locale parameter solved my issue
 `<s:DateSpinner id="dt" displayMode="date" width="100%" locale="tr_TR"/>`

Answer (score 0):

There should be folder "tr_TR" in your local Flex sdk folder - for example "FlexBuilder2Plug-in\Flex SDK 2\frameworks\locale". If it's missed in your sdk, try to download it from adobe site, it could be missed just because you PC local settings did't apply properly when you downloaded sdk.